# How do i disable specific dates on JXDatePicker

Tags: java, swing

I am doing a system (java app) connected to a mysql database. I use a `JXdatepicker`.

I need to disable specific dates that was already logged in the database.

I looked around and saw this:

```
Date[] dates = {new date()};

jXDatePicker1.getMOnthView().setUnselectableDates(dates);
```

so I tried it

```
try {
    Statement stmt = MyConnection.getConnection().createStatement();
    ResultSet rs;
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT date FROM transactions"); 
    while(rs.next()){
        Date [] dates = {fromStringToDate(rs.getString("date"))};
        JXDatePicker.getMonthView().setUnselectableDates(dates);
    }

    MyConnection.getConnection().close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

The `setUnselectableDates()` method worked, but it only disabled the last date item from my database. I'm not quite sure of how I will write it in my while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the class `ArrayList` to collect all your dates and then covert it to an array something like this:

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT date FROM transactions"); 
List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>();
while(rs.next()){
    dates.add(fromStringToDate(rs.getString("date")));
}
JXDatePicker.getMonthView().setUnselectableDates(dates.toArray(new Date[0]));
```

Comment: please edit your answer, you have syntax error, change the last line to `JXDatePicker.getMonthView().setUnselectableDates(dates.toArray(new Date[0]))`; 

and how did it works when you put the size of you array to 0 ?

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy you're welcome, but how it works if you have the size of your array 0?

Comment: @Bashir java uses the type of array only and creates an array of an appropriate size. This operation is highly optimized by JVM. But you can also create an array of the appropriate length by yourself. Something like `dates.toArray(new Date[date.size()])`.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy thank you for the valuable information

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code, you have to fill your array before applying the method

```
try {
        int nbDates=0;
        Statement stmt = MyConnection.getConnection().createStatement();
        ResultSet rs;
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM transactions"); //nombre of dates to declare array later
        nbDates = rs.getInt(1); 
        Date [] dates = new Date [nbDates]; //declare array with the size is number of total dates
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT date FROM transactions"); 
        int i=0;
        while(rs.next()){
            dates[i++]  = fromStringToDate(rs.getString("date")); //fill the array withh all dates
        }
        JXDatePicker.getMonthView().setUnselectableDates(dates); //apply your method once the array is filled
        MyConnection.getConnection().close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

or using `ArrayList` (to avoid querying twice)

```
try {
    Statement stmt = MyConnection.getConnection().createStatement();
    ResultSet rs;
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT date FROM transactions"); 
    List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>();
    while(rs.next()){
        dates.add(fromStringToDate(rs.getString("date"))); //fill the list withh all dates
    }
    JXDatePicker.getMonthView().setUnselectableDates(dates.toArray(new Date[list.size()])); //apply your method once the array is filled and convert the arraylist to array
    MyConnection.getConnection().close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```